# Do you know the inductor L3 value of the Creality V2.2 controller board?

Tags: electronics, creality-ender-5

The extruder stepper 'E' of my Ender 5 stopped working some days ago and by looking at the motherboard I found out the inductor L3 burned.

I have a Creality V2.2 (CR-10S motherboard) and I would like to change the inductor but I can't find a single datasheet of the motherboard to help me find out the inductor value.

Does anyone know it ?

[image: The burned inductor]

Comment: Do you have experience soldering surface mount elements? A new board is relatively cheap.

Comment: Perfect excuse to upgrade to a modern board. Similar boards seem to use 30 Ohm (100 MHz, SKR Mini E3) to 120 Ohm (100 MHz, Fysetc Cheetah)

Comment: Also the skr board (e3 mini v2) is same priceish, much better (tmc's properly connected), and dropin replacement.

Comment: (The Creality silent boards have the TMC stepper drivers connected in a legacy manner where they're just emulating old-style drivers and can't be configured via the firmware. Other boards connect them properly in UART mode.)

Comment: Well I have some SMD soldering experience and I did buy a new one but it was only to repair it to have a backup motherboard in case of a new disfunctionning